# Sql Server Discovery report showing features but blank instance names

Tags: sql-server

I ran Sql Server Discovery report from Installation Center, and this is what i got :
[image]

Does this indicate a correct Sql server installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm am assuming you want the db. You do not have the Database Engine installed. You can find more info about each of the SQL Server [components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx) here.